# Expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant ATMEGA

Tags: c

I want to connect atmega32 with MMC/SD Card, but I have problem is that:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL    
void uart_init(unsigned int BAUD)

unsigned long int temp_BAUD;
unsigned char F_CPU;
temp_BAUD = (F_CPU)/16;
temp_BAUD /= BAUD;
temp_BAUD--;
```

The problem is: `expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant`
Could anyone tell me what this problem is and how to solve this problem?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: you forgot ; after "void uart_init(unsigned int BAUD)"

Comment: You use the macro name `F_CPU` for your variable name `unsigned char F_CPU;` which will expands to `unsigned char 8000000UL;` which is wrong. Further you forgot the `;` after the function declaration as the comment before said.

Comment: The message probably contains some line number, doesn't it? If you get an error message or warning, please **always** tell us exactly **which** message and **where** is it reported.

Comment: @Gerhardh I see that, i'm sorry about that, i will tell clearly later !

Comment: @MichaelWalz ok, i see, thanks for your advise !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues. First of all, that number won't fit inside of a char. A char is often 8-bits, so it can contain 2^8 different values (0-255, for instance).

Second, a macro simply gets replaced by the thing it defines. So

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL 
unsigned char F_CPU;
```

becomes

```
unsigned char 8000000UL;
```

which isn't valid code. A variable needs a name, so you'd need to do something like

```
unsigned long variableContainingCPUSpeed = F_CPU;
```

which will then be replaced with

```
unsigned long variableContainingCPUSpeed = 8000000UL;
```

However, in your example you don't need to store this speed in a variable at all. For your baud computation, you use the macro directly. You could therefore simply leave out the `unsigned char F_CPU;` line.